# Jenkins pipeline script issue with wget and variables in URL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, wget, jenkins-groovy

I have checked many suggestions regarding the issue, but didn't find a suitable solution.

Initially my pipeline code was working fine but with a Jenkins security warning **The following steps that have been detected may have insecure interpolation of sensitive variables. sh: [pass, user]**

My code is as below:

```
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'Jenkins-Nexus-tech', passwordVariable: 'pass', usernameVariable: 'user')]){
                        sh "wget --user=$user --password=$pass 'https://nexus.mycompany.io/repository/updated-maven-releases/com/mycompany/project/authorization-server/${params.AuthorizationServerVersion}/authorization-server-${params.AuthorizationServerVersion}.war' "
                }
```

Warning:

```
[Pipeline] sh
Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
         Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [pass, user]
         See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
```

To avoid the Jenkins security warning as suggested in https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#interpolation-of-sensitive-environment-variables , I have modified my code as below. But with different permutation and combination of single and double quotes it is not working. It is throwing **Bad substitution** error:

```
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'Jenkins-Nexus-tech', passwordVariable: 'pass', usernameVariable: 'user')]){
                        sh 'wget --user=$user --password=$pass \"https://nexus.mycompany.io/repository/updated-maven-releases/com/mycompany/project/authorization-server/${params.AuthorizationServerVersion}/authorization-server-${params.AuthorizationServerVersion}.war\" '
                }
```

I have tried with 3 single quotes. with this I am not getting the warning but it is unable to substitute the variables in the wget URL:

```
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'Jenkins-Nexus-tech', passwordVariable: 'pass', usernameVariable: 'user')]){
                        sh '''wget --user=$user --password=$pass 'https://nexus.mycompany.io/repository/updated-maven-releases/com/mycompany/project/authorization-server/${params.AuthorizationServerVersion}/authorization-server-${params.AuthorizationServerVersion}.war' '''
                }
```

Error is as below as it can't substitute the values of the variable

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ wget --user=**** --password=**** https://nexus.mycompany.io/repository/updated-maven-releases/com/mycompany/project/authorization-server/${params.AuthorizationServerVersion}/authorization-server-${params.AuthorizationServerVersion}.war
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 com/mycompany/project/authorization-server/${params.AuthorizationServerVersion}/authorization-server-${params.AuthorizationServerVersion}.war
ERROR 404: com/mycompany/project/authorization-server/${params.AuthorizationServerVersion}/authorization-server-${params.AuthorizationServerVersion}.war.
```

It would be really great if someone can assist here.

Comment: Please brush up on Groovy string interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion outlined in the [page you mention](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#interpolation-of-sensitive-environment-variables) suggests you do not use [Groovy string interpolation](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation) to pass sensitive data to `sh` steps. The suggestion is to let the `sh` script instead get the values from the environment.

However, in your case you still need the value held in the `params.AuthorizationServerVersion` in your `sh` step.

Groovy string interpolation is only used when the string is within double quotes. String interpolation is turned off when the string is in single quotes.

When a string is in double quotes, you can escape `$`s using a backslash. This will prevent inserting the contents of a variable into the string when you don't want this to occur.

What you can do, then, is use double quotes, escape the `$`s on the variables you want to read from the environment, and leave the `$`s un-escaped on the variables you want to access directly from your Groovy code.

An example, using the [`withCredentials` plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/):

```
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'mytoken', variable: 'THE_TOKEN')]) {
    sh "some_command --that-uses \$THE_TOKEN --as-an-environment-variable --and-also-uses $params.A_PARAMETER"
}
```

Here, the token is injected into the environment as a secret, and is used in the `sh` script by escaping the `$`. This means the actual Unix shell (bash, zsh, or whatever) will get the literal `$` and expand it as specified by that shell language.

The `$` for `$params.A_PARAMETER` is not escaped, and is within double quotes, so Groovy will perform string interpolation and replace `$params.A_PARAMETER` with the value of the parameter at runtime as the string is constructed in memory, before the string is passed as an argument to the `sh` step.

In your specific case, this is what you can use (within your `withCredentials` block, of course):

```
sh "wget --user=\$user --password=\$pass 'https://nexus.mycompany.io/repository/updated-maven-releases/com/mycompany/project/authorization-server/${params.AuthorizationServerVersion}/authorization-server-${params.AuthorizationServerVersion}.war'"
```

Note that the `$` on `$user` and `$pass` are escaped, but the `$` on `${params.AuthorizationServerVersion}` is not escaped.

Comment: hey @Shane, I am trying the same by escaping `$` but its passing the variable itself to the sh command, like `$Host`. What could be wrong here?